# Using Apache's mod rewrite how to redirect depending the query string?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Using Apache's mod rewrite how to redirect `foo.php?r=ok` to `boo.php` (that is, depending the query string: if `r` = `ok` then redirect).

Answer (score 0):

you can't use query string (the string after "?" character) as variable for rewrite, because query string is not a part of URL path.

you need to modify foo.php?r=ok to some string path like "foo.php/redirect/"

Answer (score 0):

From [the Apache manual discussing mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> If you wish to match against the
>   hostname, port, or query string, use a
>   RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST},
>   %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING}
>   variables respectively.

Look closely at **RewriteRules** and **RewriteConditions**

**EDIT:** Added a working example

The RegEx use to write these is just pure heaven </sarcasm>

Any how... here's a simple rule (Apache2, Mac OS X 10.5.8)

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(foo\.php)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (r=ok) 
RewriteRule (foo\.php)      /bar.php [R]
```

I tested this for as many obvious caveats that I could think of (ie r=ko, oof.php, foo.php?r=o), but couldn't break it.

Comment: I think I can break it with r=%6F%66 (which is 'ok' urlencoded). QUERY_STRING is un-decoded string. And no way to get the decoded one.